# Which is the simplest way to install PHP

Tags: php, installation

I am very new to php.... please tell me the most easiest way to install it and run a sample app, some tutorials which do that....

I read something on internet but most of the time, all the tutorials were not ok... so i decided to ask here to find someone's else opinion...

Thanks

Comment: Easiest ways leads to Hell...

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting, environment: Windows Xp service pack 2

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows, you can use [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) which is pretty straightforward (just click next 3 times and you have Apache+mySql+PHP. For you development box of course (not for production).

Answer (score 1):

In windows I would use WAMP or XAMP, in OSX I would use either the Native php installs or MAMP if you want to make it easy to configure.. On linux you should compile it from source.

**Edit:** As samuel says, only use these on Development machines, you should always compile your own versions for a production box!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MS Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/).

Answer (score 0):

I use [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) it sets up Apache/PHP/MySQL and phpMyAdmin in about 5 clicks!